# GWT website routing

Tags: gwt, routes

I visited new [GWT website](http://www.gwtproject.org/) and noticed that after clicking on tree items - link is changing without adding hash (for example, http://www.gwtproject.org/books.html). I know how to do url routing using hashes, but how URL routing is made in GWT website (and possibly can be made)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's commonly called [HTML5 PushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). A new way of dealing with the browser history by changing the URL without necessarily reloading the page. By listening on `popstate` events you can dynamically change your page just like using the hashtag method, with the benefit of having cleaner URLs and out of the box crawlability.

Have a look at the gwt website [source](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt-site-webapp/+/master/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/site/webapp/client/GWTProjectEntryPoint.java). Internally uses the GQuery library (jQuery port for GWT) that leverages such `pushState` methodology.

EDIT: If you want to take benefit of `pushState` right from GWT (since it does not natively support it), you can also have a look at [Johannes Barop's pushState project](https://github.com/jbarop/gwt-pushstate).